# How to add a texture to a section that is already a part of a larger object with one?

Tags: modeling, texturing, materials, image

Sorry for the super broad question title that probably has nothing to do with the actual question. It's hard trying to put this stuff into words since I don't really know what I'm talking about.

My problem here is that there's a specific area that I want to add a texture to. However, it's actually a part of a bigger part that already has a texture on it. (If that makes sense). Switching the textures won't work.

[image: pink hair]
I googled around and read about how the hot pink color is because I'm missing a texture somewhere. (Correct me if I'm wrong, I'm still so new at this). The pink hair only shows up when I show the textures on "soldier76_body", but not on any other part. This definitely confirms that my lack of hair texture is rooted there.

[image: but now white hair??]
Whenever I switch what I'm looking at, like the mask now, the actual hair texture does show up.

I know that it's something to do with the body texture, since it seems to be an isolated incident.

I've already tried adding different textures to the body, but when I do that my model is completely white from the hair texture.

I've already tried duplicating the model, and copying only the hair section and trying to add the separate texture to that and attaching it tot he original model, but it doesn't work.

What exactly am I doing wrong and why did is this happening?

[image]

Comment: Is your question about the pink texture (image not found), or about adding another texture over part that already has a texture?

Comment: Sorry that it was so confusing ;-; The first image is just showing the hot pink thing over the hair section because there's no actual hair texture. Instead, the entire texture is just the clothes and accessories, but not the hair. I really have no idea how to put something there.

Comment: I'd add a separate material to the hair (see http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/516/599), as chances are you'll want different shading for the hair than for the suit etc. Once you have the hair on a separate material, you can give it a texture pretty much like normal.

Comment: I can't select the hair on it's own, instead it'll just select the entire body. Is there anything I can do to change that?

Comment: Could you upload your model to http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ ? Before doing that, please pack your textures into it. "File -> External Data -> Pack all into .blend"

Comment: http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/1712/ Also, if the way I added the textures and materials are incorrect, please let me know. I just started using Blender today so I'm still really new at this.

Comment: I'm also using the faceoff.png texture for the body, not any of the other colors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First the odd thing. I don't know the origin of your model, but every mesh of your model has a copy, that can be identified by the .001 extension in the Outliner. This does make things very confusing, so I'm going to work on the copy while the original will be hidden.

[image: original hidden, copy as work model]

## Analyzing the Mesh

As I expected, your model is divided into several meshes, with each of them containing sub-meshes. These sub-meshes don't share vertices so they can easily selected in Edit Mode by clicking on one of the vertices and then expand the selection by hitting <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Numpad +</kbd> until the whole sub-mesh is selected.

[image: selecting the hair mesh]

After selecting the hair mesh, we see the UV layout in the UV/Image Editor. Let's keep it as it is. We also recognize the name of the currently assigned texture, which is faceoff.png. We also have a material in the material editor that goes by the same name, so let's keep this convention.

[image: hair UV, texture name and material]

## Preparing and assigning the Material

If we click on the image selector in the UV/Image Editor we find an image named s76_hair.png.

[image]

Now we create a new material named s76_hair and assign the right texture to a new slot. (Texture names aren't necessarily file names, I chose the first one that matches the UV I looked up in the image editor - in this case it's Texture.006). To play it safe, we also assign the UV map for the correct mapping.

[image: create material and assign texture]

In the last step we assign the material to the hair mesh. With the hair mesh still selected, we go to the Material Editor, select our newly created material and hit "Assign".

[image: assign material to hair mesh]

If we look at our model in Texture Paint mode, we'll see that now the correct texture shows on the mesh.

[image: check result]

[image]